# can vim syntastic plugin read from pkgconfig for all include files

Tags: vim, syntastic

I am using vim syntastic plugin.
All the depedent library are installed at different paths.
There are so many libraries so I cannot give all name in syntactic_include_dirs

Can syntastic include all headers recursively from a folder.?
Or
Can it read from pkg-config and include all headers?

In my case,
Syntastic shows header missing and dont show other errors,at least it should show other errors?

Comment: _Can it read from pkg-config and include all headers?_ - No, but you can tell it to read `gcc` options from a file.  Read the manual to find out how.  _Syntastic shows header missing and dont show other errors,at least it should show other errors?_ - That's `gcc` treating missing includes as fatal errors.  Switch to CLang, or submit a feature request to the GCC project.

Comment: Thank you very much